# Getting error on running sender.py and receiver.py file related to RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq

Error stack seen on running the sender and receiver files

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/A3245643/PycharmProjects/events/receive.py", line 7, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
  File "C:\Users\A6002043\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 359, in __init__
    self._impl = self._create_connection(parameters, _impl_class)
  File "C:\Users\A6002043\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 450, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError
```

send.py file acts as producer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='iptbotQueue')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='test-exchange',
                      routing_key='iptbotQueue',
                      body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")

connection.close()
```

recieve.py acts as consumer

```
# from send import channel


import pika, sys, os


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='iptbotQueue')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(queue='iptbotQueue',
                      auto_ack=True,
                      on_message_callback=callback)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

I have already set the rabbit mq , so should I replace the localhost value with the url seen below in image?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I need to provide the IP address ( example : 172.11.12.33) for localhost value

or just host name without adding "http" example **slacktestbot-mq.omnitank.bestbuy.com**